# Angular TemplateRef Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I have to place all the `ngx-bootstrap modals` in a single `component.html` so that I can access any modal from anywhere.

I have tried the below code in

```
header.componentn.html
<button (click)="Login(loginModal)">Login</button>

header.cmponent.ts
@Input() myModal: AppModalsComponent;
bsModalRef: BsModalRef;
Login(template:TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.myModal.openModal(template);
}

app-modals.component.html
<ng-template #loginModal>
    <div class="modal-body">Login Here</div>
 </ng-template>

app-modals.component.ts
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.config);
}
```

Complete code at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ft2jn).

I'm pasing a template Reference object from HTML. It is getting undefined in `ts`. I think this is bexause the corresponding ng-template is not present in same HTML.
How to reslove this?

Comment: Since the StackBlitz link may become invalid or irrelevant in the future, please include also the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation you call `show()` on the modal service and

> Pass a TemplateRef or a component as a first argument and config as a second (optionally).

To make sharing these modals easier I would just make each modal it's own component. You will need to make sure you declare it as an `entryComponent` in the `app.module`.

Then in whichever component needs to open the modal you can just inject the modal service and then pass the ModalComponent you want it to create.

modal.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  template: '<div class="modal-body">Login Here</div>'
})
export class ModalComponent {}
```

some.componet.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some',
  template: '<button (click)="openModal">Open the modal</button>'
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(public modalService: BsModalService) { }

  openModal() {
    this.modalService.show(ModalComponent);
  }
}
```

## [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqcjh6)

Comment: The modal is not like the one in https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Comment: For a modal that you will create inline inside of a component it makes sense to use the template method. But since you are looking to share these modals across your entire app then the method described here https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component makes more sense for your use case.

Comment: Thankyou. And now I'm having singup modal also. Do I need to maintain one more lik signup.component.html & signup.component.ts for that

Comment: Yes. This will help separate the concerns and logic of the different modals since login and singup perform different functions.

Comment: Okay Thankyou Teddy Steme